# CodeIgniter Undefined Property load not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

So I'm trying to load a model in CodeIgniter so I can make a function call. My code looks like:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    define('DEFAULT_PAGE', true);
    $this->pageTitle('Account Login');
    $email = $this->request->getVar('email');

    $this->load->model('UserAccountIdxModel');
    $acc = $this->UserAccountIdx->getUserAccount($email);
```

When I run it, I get an error saying `'Undefined property: App\Controllers\Account::$load'`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I thought the load method worked universally.

I'm calling my code from `main/Controllers/Account.php` and I'm trying to load the model in `main/Models/UserAccountIdxModel.php`. I've tried changing the path of the model but to no avail. Any ideas?

Just for clarification, I tried using a relative path and using a .php extension but neither of those fixed the problem either.

Comment: Your naming scheme isn't recommended. Should be `Some_thing_model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is your model file name not a valid. make your codes like following

rename your file like this `UserAccountIdx_model.php`

```
main/Models/UserAccountIdx_model.php
```

inside the `UserAccountIdx_model.php` class should be like this

```
class UserAccountIdx_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function getUserAccount($email){
        // your code
    }
}
```

now call the model function in controller in following ways

```
$this->load->model('UserAccountIdx_model');
$acc = $this->UserAccountIdx_model->getUserAccount($email);
```

OR

```
$this->load->model('UserAccountIdx_model','user'); // assign model name to `user`
$acc = $this->user->getUserAccount($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You load model `UserAccountIdxModel` and use `UserAccountIdx`

both name should same

```
$this->load->model('UserAccountIdxModel');
$acc = $this->UserAccountIdx->getUserAccount($email);
```

As below

```
$this->load->model('UserAccountIdxModel');
$acc = $this->UserAccountIdxModel->getUserAccount($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use _ in model name and try the below code it will definitely help you.

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('UserAccountIdx_Model');
}
```

then use :-

```
$acc = $this->UserAccountIdx_Model->getUserAccount($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('database');
    $this->load->model('UserAccountIdxModel', 'u_model');

}
```

And use it :

`$acc = $this->u_model->getUserAccount($email);`